# Send RSS feeds to Kindle

Tags: rss, kindle

Is there a way to automatically send RSS feeds from Google Reader to Kindle every day at a scheduled time? Basically I would like to receive the title of the unread feeds, then when I click that feed item would be downloaded to Kindle.

Comment: Google Reader is shutting down July 1, 2013.

Answer (score 2):

[KindleSend](http://www.kindlesend.com) automatically downloads RSS feeds, creates an ebook, and sends it to your Kindle on a scheduled basis. They include scheduled syncing at 1am (GMT), but if you want to specify the exact time or send more than 12 different RSS feeds then you need to pay $20 per year.

Comment: Tried with qwantz.com, got the posts without cartoon images -- pretty useless if you ask me

Comment: [KindleSend](http://www.kindlesend.com/) seems to be dead. The website is replaced by an advertisement site.

Answer (score 1):

[Readability](http://www.readability.com) and [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com) are free web services. At first you should make accounts in [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com), Readability and Instapaper (all free). So, you should make your recipe in IFTTT with reference recipe which you can find in 'browse' menu.

Comment: Not even a link to the recipe? Bah!

Comment: [Readability shut down permanently on September 30, 2016](https://medium.com/@readability/the-readability-bookmarking-service-will-shut-down-on-september-30-2016-1641cc18e02b#.fhop5yby1)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com) to send a compilation of your unread articles to your kindle

Use Feedly to organize your feeds.

Then use IFTTT to send new posts in any given feedly category to Instapaper.

You can send up to ten articles at a time whenever you want nicely compiled in one document. Or you can set a time to send up to ten articles automatically each day. You could set up multiple IFTTT recipes for different categories.

I found this idea at http://ljcbluemuse.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-read-blogs-on-your-kindle-free.html

Answer (score 0):

[Sendtoreader Periodicals](http://sendtoreader.com/periodicals) does just that. You'll need to make a bundle inside your google reader, containing the feeds you'd like to receive on your Kindle. Bundle gives you RSS link which you'll need setting up sendtoreader periodical. The service will deliver full-text articles, not just titles.

Answer (score 0):

**[Newstoebook.com](http://newstoebook.com)** converts any RSS/Atom feed, or Google Reader subscription into EPUB or Kindle ebook.